# Android getContentResolver NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I am new in Android. When `getContentResolver()` function is called I always get `NullPointerException`. I don't know why. Code is below:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_job_details)
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.main)
public class JobDetailsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Extra
    Job jobObject;

    @ViewById
    ListView lwPickups;

    PickupAdapter adapter;

    @AfterViews
    public void afterViews() {
            initActionBar();

            adapter = new PickupAdapter(JobDetailsActivity.this,
                            R.layout.row_pickup, R.id.twPickup, jobObject.getPickups());
            lwPickups.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private void initActionBar() {
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setTitle(jobObject.getDesc());
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    }
```

Then I tried to run query event in the same class:

```
    boolean result=queryEvent("123",JobDetailsActivity.this);
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public boolean queryEvent(String event_id,Context context) {
            String[] projection= new String[]{Events.TITLE};
            ContentResolver contentResolver=context.getContentResolver(); // NullPointerException
            Cursor calCursor=contentResolver.query(Events.CONTENT_URI, projection, Events._ID+"="+event_id, null, null);
            if(calCursor.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                            String id = calCursor.getString(0);
                            if(id==event_id){
                                    return true;
                            }
                    }while(calCursor.moveToNext());
            }
            return false;
    }

}
```

Could some one help?Does it cause of can't access getContentResolver() before the Activity is created? If it does,in this case,where should I put getContentResolver() as I use @EActivity(R.layout.activity_job_details)? Thanks

Comment: maybe could be a error calling `Activity context`, try `this.getApplicationContext()`instead `JobDetailsActivity.this` like        `boolean result=queryEvent("123",this.getApplicationContext());`

Comment: it still not work after change to this.getApplicationContext().I have pasted logCat:

Comment: 05-06 22:50:33.058: E/AndroidRuntime(5267): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 22:50:33.058: E/AndroidRuntime(5267):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)

Comment: This time nullpointerexception happens in getApplicationContext